# Type traits of float (int) const

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

When I tried my own implementation of type traits, I compared my results with std `<type_traits>`. I tried to check type traits of type `float (int) const`, which I thought should be function. I got strange results, so I tried to pass this type to std type traits. Here is my test code:

```
std::cout << std::is_function<float (int) const>::value;
std::cout << std::is_compound<float(int) const>::value;
std::cout << std::is_pointer<float(int)const>::value;
std::cout << std::is_class<float(int)const>::value;
std::cout << std::is_union<float(int)const>::value;
std::cout << std::is_member_pointer<float(int)const>::value;
std::cout << std::is_array<float(int)const>::value;
std::cout << std::is_scalar<float(int)const>::value;
std::cout << std::is_enum<float(int)const>::value;
std::cout << std::is_object<float(int)const>::value;
```

Output of this test was following:

```
0100000001
```

Meaning, that this type is compound & object, but not scalar. According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/, it should be class, union or array, none of which is true. What should be correct result for this type? I am using MSVC 2015.

Comment: What part of the page you linked makes you think `float(int) const` should be a class, union, or array type?

Comment: The fact that it is compound, object but not scalar leaves only these 3 possibilities.

Comment: Also, you've posted 10 lines that should print out one bit of output each, but only 8 bits of output. Your code and output don't match.

Comment: `float(int) const` shouldn't be an object type. It's a function type. Does MSVC 2015 really say it's not a function type? The output should look like [this](http://ideone.com/wSThOm).

Comment: Yes, it does. So it must be a bug in MSVC library.

Comment: @user2357112: Those are not "bits".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the MSVS implementation; [`float(int) const` is both function and compound](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5d5de683f167066).

Raise it on Connect, if it's not already there (which it doesn't seem to be).

I suspect the trailing `const` (which is supposed to be ignored/stripped) is throwing things off.

Comment: It seems that in case of template partial specialization for functions, remove_cv does not work. GCC implementation is specializing for every possible cv combination.